# Why do people still use SFTP jails based on SSH chroot rather than namespace capabilities of Systemd?

Tags: systemd, chroot, openssh, namespace

The idea might be stupid or not feasible, I don't know, but I can't find any reference about this...

As you may know (and as SE definitely knows!), one of the common steps used to tighten SSH security, provided file access is enough, is to lock the user in a chroot. OpenSSH has been providing such a chroot-based jail for years now.

However that approach lacks flexibility (all-or-nothing, SFTP only, etc.) and it comes down to abusing a system call (which has security implications, hence the "the jail must be owned by root" and other recommendations rarely understood).

Now that OpenSSH is provided as a `sshd.socket` and `sshd@.service`, I am tempted to use Linux namespace (which I get for free then) to restrain my users instead.

I am just very surprise that I found literally nothing on that alternative scheme. So my question is, is there any reason not to use namespaces instead of chroot for that kind of usage?

Comment: "abusing" is a strange verb to associate with the standard `chroot(2)` system call

Comment: And that exact same man page explains at length that chroot purpose is not security: "chroot()  changes  the  root  directory  of the calling process" and "This call changes an ingredient in the pathname resolution process and does  nothing  else." and "it  is  not  intended to be used for any kind of security purpose". Hence, "abusing" in that specific context. :)

Comment: I see that perfectly closed questions (at the end of my description, not my title) are also quickly flagged these days even though I find the (now accepted) answer spot on and perfectly acceptable. But I understand that black or white answers are far more appealing than grey ones. A shame though that people still confuse "complicated" and "subjective"... Semantically, one only needs 1 counter example to answer a "is there any reason not to..." type of question... A real shame...

Comment: time wasted in comments might be better spent on the question e.g. instead of "why do people" (who?) a not-opinion "what are the advantages of linux namespaces vs. chroot", use a not-opinion verb instead of the strange abuse one, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try that and report back how it works. In everything, there is somebody first one!

But my concern is that it would not work. The `chroot` from OpenSSH is called after all the key exchange, authentication and everything is done, but Systemd would force the namespaces even before starting the sshd process (if I understand its behavior correctly) and it might not be able to process the user authentication. Also in the service file, you are not able to differentiate users connecting so you would namespace all of them? How would you connect as a normal admin user to maintain this system? I believe it is certainly a good idea and useful for other services, but I don't believe you would be able to "abuse" it (for free) to suit your needs for OpenSSH.

Comment: I just assumed that `sshd.socket` did the authentication and just spawned `sshd@<username>.service` before forwarding the connection. It is indeed not the case which means that OpenSSH itself must be aware and use namespaces. Thank you.